# How can I write a for loop for a matrix based on conditions from another matrix?

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, matrix

I'm trying to get a new matrix based on conditions in another matrix. The original matrix (matrix 1) looks like this:

```
[empty] |V1     |V2     |V3    |V4    |V5    |....  |V17   | V18
1       |NA     |NA     |name1 |name2 |name3 |....  |name15|NA
2       |abc    |2016   |NA    |10    |20    |....  |NA    |name1
3       |abc    |2016   |NA    |10    |20    |....  |NA    |name2
4       |abc    |2016   |NA    |10    |20    |....  |NA    |name3
...     |abc    |2016   |NA    |10    |20    |....  |NA    |....
16      |abc    |2016   |NA    |10    |20    |....  |NA    |name15
```

What I'm trying to code is a new matrix (matrix 2) with the following condition: if the value of the first line of matrix 1 in the concerning column equals the value of the last column of matrix 1 in the concerning line, matrix 2 should write down the value that was originally in matrix 1 in the concerning cell; if the condition isn't true, it should write "NA". For example, in line 2, the fourth and the fifth column should be replaced by "NA", whereas in line 3, the fourth column should stay "10" and the fifth should be replaced by "NA".
Here's what I've coded so far:

```
a<-seq(1:16)  
b<-seq(1:18)

matrix2<- matrix(nrow=16, ncol=18)

for(i in 1:dim(matrix2)[1]) {
 for(j in 1:dim(matrix2)[2]) {
  matrix2[i,j] = if("matrix1[a,b]"=="matrix1[a,18]") {"matrix1[a,b]"} else {"NA"}
  }
}
print(matrix2)
```

What is returned is a matrix with 16 rows and 18 columns containing "NA". I am almost sure that there's more than just one problem with my code. Also, in fact, the condition should only be applied for matrix1[2:16,3:17] but I don't have a clue how to write this. Thank you a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is a bit confusing, but I read your post to mean in pseudo-math:

```
x_new[i,j]= x[i,j] if x[i,j]=x[i,J] and else NA, for all i,j
```

where `J` is the number of columns in your matrix.

This can be achieved with a simple `ifelse` statement. Consider:

```
set.seed(42)
mat <- matrix(sample(1:3, 9, T), ncol=3)
mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    3    3
[2,]    3    2    1
[3,]    1    2    2

mat2 <- ifelse(mat==mat[,ncol(mat)], mat, NA)
mat2
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    3    3    3
[2,]   NA   NA    1
[3,]   NA    2    2
```

Here, `ncol(mat)` indicates the last column of your matrix. You can easily adjust these to your needs. If you want to exclude the first column, use `mat[,-1]` instead, as in

```
mat2 <- ifelse(mat[,-1]==mat[,ncol(mat)], mat[,-1], NA)
```

---

**Edit:** you clarified that you want the check for equality only for the first row. This can be achieved with something along the following lines. First, let's create a matrix with different number of rows and columns, as in your example:

```
set.seed(42)
mat <- matrix(sample(1:3, 12, T), ncol=4)
mat
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    3    3    3
[2,]    3    2    1    2
[3,]    1    2    2    3
```

Now, we need to know for each combination of entry in the first row and last column if they are equal. `outer` can do that:

```
ind <- t(outer(mat[1,], mat[,ncol(mat)], FUN = `==`))
ind
      [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
[1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
[2,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

This can be used with a simple `ifelse`-statement.

```
mat2 <- ifelse(ind, mat, NA)
mat2
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    3    3    3    3
[2,]   NA   NA   NA   NA
[3,]    1    2    2    3
```

As before, you can exclude the first or last column with the usual subsetting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help already! I'm sorry for the confusing description - trying to do better now. Your code results in a matrix containing nothing but the names (name1, name2, etc.) in the last column (and NA-values). What I'd need, though, is a matrix with the names in the the last column AND the actual data (see my question, examples used were 10 and 20) - but only in those cells for which the name at the end of the line is the same one as the name in the top line directly above the cell. Line three e.g. should result in NA, NA, NA, 10, NA, .., name2. I hope it is more clear now.